# How can I check answers of a textfield using swift?

Tags: swift, string, xcode

I am writing a basic quiz app in Xcode using a single page and need help on how I can check the answers. I have a string of questions and answers that match up. When the user inputs his answer in the text field how can I check if it is correct?

```
@IBOutlet var questionLabel:UILabel!
@IBOutlet var answerField:UITextField!
@IBOutlet var instructionsLabel:UILabel!


let questions:[String] = ["In what country is the Christ the Redeemer statue located in?", "In what country is Machu Picchu lacated in?", "In what country is the Taj Mahal located in?", "In what country is the Great Pyramids of Giza located in?","In what country is Petra located in?","In what country is the Great Wall located in?", "In what country is the ruins if Chichen Itza located in?"]
let answers:[String] = ["Brazil", "Peru", "India", "Egypt", "Jordan", "China", "Mexico"]


var currentQuestionIndex:Int = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    currentQuestionIndex = questions.count - 1
}
@IBAction func showNextQuestion(sender:AnyObject){

    if(currentQuestionIndex<questions.count-1) {
        currentQuestionIndex = currentQuestionIndex + 1
    } else {
        currentQuestionIndex = 0
    }
    questionLabel.text = questions[currentQuestionIndex]

}

@IBAction func checkAnswer(){

}

}
```

Comment: Can you show your failed attempts? That way, I can see where your misunderstanding is, or what concept you don't get. You can [edit] your question.

Comment: You need an outlet to your text field

Comment: I have one just forgot to post it. Sorry, new to all of this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to check the answer

```
@IBAction func checkAnswer() {
    guard let answer = answerField.text, !answer.isEmpty else {
        //answer is empty
        return
    }

    if answers[currentQuestionIndex].lowercased() == answer.lowercased() {
        //correct answer found
    } else {
        //Incorrect answer
    }
}
```

Note that I haven't written any code to display the result to the user but you could for instance have a Label where you write a message where I have just written a comment. A more advanced solution could be to display the result message as an alert or in a sheet.